# Can someone fix the technoloy in the tour?

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the [Tour](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/tour):

> for professionals in renewable energy and other clean **technoloy**

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Jan. Well spotted. Fixed now.